# React Native 0.60.5 - receive binary data over WebSocket

Tags: react-native, websocket, binary

I open a WebSocket connection from my RN 0.60.5 app to my Node.js 
 server and send binary data just fine (the app sends, the server receives. The server uses [ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws)). But when I send binary data from the server, my app receives an empty ArrayBuffer. I believe my server code is right, because when I connect from my browser I receive binary data just fine.

As far as I remember, previously it was not possible even to send binary data from an RN app over a WebSocket. Am I missing something or binary transfers are supported only partially for now?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the exact same problem and found that I needed to set the binaryType of the websocket object to 'blob'

```
var websocket = new WebSocket("ws://10.10.10.1/stream")
websocket.binaryType = 'blob';

websocket.onmessage = (event) => { ... }
```

After that then I was able to pass the event.data into a FileReader to use the data, for my use case anyway.

Comment: Jesus! Have they finally done it? That line never helped. Which version of RN are you using?

Comment: Apparently! Worked for me anyway, I'm using 0.61.5 in my project at the moment

Comment: I'm using react 16.13.1 and react-native 0.63.3 and I get "Error: FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer is not implemented" or "TypeError: reader.readAsBinaryString is not a function". How did you get the data from the blob?

Comment: I ended up using this: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21209

Comment: @RobinBobin In my case the data being received was JSON, so I used reader.readAsText(event.data, "UTF-8"); then parsed to JSON